# Is there a way to make custom commands available in namespace or an object in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have a typescript project with few "Cypress Custom Commands" that perform navigations like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('goToHome', () => { /* Logic here */ });
Cypress.Commands.add('goToProducts', () => { /* Logic here */ });
```

Now. I can run these commands like this: `cy.goToHome();`

However, I want these commands to **`not`** be accessible from the `cy` object, instead I want to make these commands to be accessible from a custom object like this:

`cy.header.goToHome();` or `cy.getHeader().goToHome();`

Is there a way to do this in Cypress?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always define a class that contains functions that will be accessible only from that namespace. A great way to organize code and keep it tidy.

For example, add a file navigation.js to your support folder. Add the following code:

```
class Navigation {


   goToHome(){ /* Logic here */ }

   goToProducts() { /* Logic here */ }

}

export default new Navigation();
```

Afterwards, import this into your spec file appropriately :

```
import Navigation from '../../support/navigation';
```

Then, inside your spec file you will be able to access these functions through the Navigation namespace. For example :

```
it('I can navigate to the homepage', function() {

    Navigation.goToHome();
    
})
```

Hope this is what you meant, and it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer, I know that I can create a helper class and have my helper function there. But I wanted to know if there is a way to make it accessible from the global `cy` object.